# Программный перезапуск приложения

Tags: android

Спрашивается про то, как  сделать так, чтобы по нажатии кнопки в приложении перезагрузить это приложение. Выглядит это так: пользователь видит диалог содержания: "Необходимо перезагрузить приложение. Выполнить сейчас?" На диалоге 2 кнопки: "Сейчас" и "Позже" (вручную). Необходимо при нажатии кнопки сейчас закрыть приложение, выгрузить его из памяти и запустить заново.

Возможно вместо диалога использовать Нотификацию. И при тапе по ней перезапускать приложение.

Comment: А зачем такое может понадобится?

Comment: В Линухах для таких дел есть cron. Можно попробовать копнуть в эту сторону.

Comment: Не стоит копать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хрень какая-то конечно, но напишите сервис, который будет останавливать и запускать приложение.